# Bash: read lines into an array *without* touching IFS

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to read the lines of output from a subshell into an array, and I'm not willing to set IFS because it's global. I don't want one part of the script to affect the following parts, because that's poor practice and I refuse to do it. Reverting IFS after the command is not an option because it's too much trouble to keep the reversion in the right place after editing the script. How can I explain to bash that I want each array element to contain an entire line, without having to set any global variables that will destroy future commands?

Here's an example showing the unwanted stickiness of IFS:

```
lines=($(egrep "^-o"  speccmds.cmd))
echo "${#lines[@]} lines without IFS"

IFS=$'\r\n' lines=($(egrep "^-o" speccmds.cmd))
echo "${#lines[@]} lines with IFS"

lines=($(egrep "^-o"  speccmds.cmd))
echo "${#lines[@]} lines without IFS?"
```

The output is:

```
42 lines without IFS
6 lines with IFS
6 lines without IFS?
```

Comment: You can save the value of IFS and restore it after you're done with the “special” value. This is done quite a bit.

Comment: Even saving and restoring is more work than is necessary -- you can just set IFS in a manner completely local to the `read` command itself.

Comment: It sounds you're using `IFS=$'\n'; array=( $value )` to split a value. This doesn't work properly unless you also `set -f`. Use mapfile or a while read loop instead.

Comment: Indeed -- `array=( $(command) )` is evil. Don't ever do that.

Comment: What is evil and godless about `array=( $(command) )`? It does what I want, except that changes to IFS are not local.

Comment: @ByronHawkins, no, it doesn't do what you want. Look at what happens when `$(command)` includes a `*` in its output surrounded by characters from `IFS`. (...or **not** surrounded by characters from `IFS`, if you have `shopt -s nullglob` enabled; in that case, output with square brackets is full of surprises too).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks, I had no idea about that! Fine, I'll use `read -a`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is probably based on a misconception.

`IFS=foo read` **does not** change IFS outside of the read operation itself.

Thus, this would have side effects, and should be avoided:

```
IFS=
declare -a array
while read -r; do
  array+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(your-subshell-here)
```

...but this is perfectly side-effect free:

```
declare -a array
while IFS= read -r; do
  array+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(your-subshell-here)
```

With bash 4.0 or newer, there's also the option of `readarray` or `mapfile` (synonyms for the same operation):

```
mapfile -t array < <(your-subshell-here)
```

---

In examples later added to your answer, you have code along the lines of:

```
lines=($(egrep "^-o"  speccmds.cmd))
```

The better way to write this is:

```
mapfile -t lines < <(egrep "^-o"  speccmds.cmd)
```

Comment: I just added an example to clarify. In the case I am trying to use, IFS has unwanted stickiness.

Comment: @ByronHawkins, the general answer is "don't do that" -- which is to say that there's never a good reason to change the global value of IFS. The examples I give above provide specific ways to Not Do That. If you gave a more explicit example of your use case, I could provide a more explicit way to, again, not rely on a sticky use of IFS.

Comment: Ahh. You did indeed add an example. Don't do that; use `read -a` or `mapfile` instead.

Comment: One more problem: I'm in msys on Windows (a problem already...) and I only have bash 3.1, so no `mapfile`. Using `read -a` doesn't work with subshell output because the subshell eats up the newlines before returning. Is there any other way to get whole lines?

Comment: @ByronHawkins, the second code block ("perfectly side-effect free") will give whole lines; its only disadvantage vs mapfile/readarray is decreased terseness. By the way, if you wanted to take input separated by NULs rather than by newlines, the only change necessary would be to add `-d ''` to the `read` command.

Comment: ...as for `read -a`, its use is primarily focused on cases where you're splitting a single line into an array, rather than cases where you're reading multiple lines into an array.

Answer (score 6):

Are you trying to store the *lines* of the output in an array, or  the *words* of *each* line?

1. lines

   ```
   mapfile -t arrayname < <(your subshell)
   ```

   This does not use IFS at all.
2. words

   ```
   (your subshell) | while IFS=: read -ra words; do ...
   ```

   The form `var=value command args...` puts the `var` variable into the environment of the `command`, and does not affect the current shell's environment.